# Why don't we include $\pm\infty$ in $\mathbb R$?

Tags: analysis

> Why don't we include $\pm\infty$ in $\mathbb R$?

If we do so, many equations will got real solution (e.g. $2^x=0$), and $\mathbb R$ will be much more complete. Why don't we do so?

Thank you.

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is a field.  The extended real number system $\overline{\mathbb R}$ is not a field.  Both systems have their uses.

Comment: Because algebra starts failing. What is $\infty - \infty$ or $0 \cdot \infty$?

Comment: @nik we could define these operations, no?

Comment: @user42912: We can define something, yes, but there no nice and satisfying definition. For example, what would you define $\infty - \infty$ as?

Comment: @nik maybe zero?

Comment: @user42912: But then $\infty - (\infty + 1) = \infty - \infty = 0 \neq (\infty - \infty) + 1 = 1$. So you lose associativity. There are many problems like that with infinity.

Comment: @nik It may be a naive question but: What's the problem in losing associativity?

Comment: @BandeiraGustavo It means if you have an expression like $a + (b + c)$, then you cannot algebraically rearrange it to $(a + b) + c$, which could be prohibitively limiting.

Comment: Plus and minus infinity are not numbers, but rather concepts, so that's a good reason not to include them among numbers. You cannot change what $\mathbb R$ **is**. It is what it is. You don't get to pick what is included in it.

Comment: What I mean by "you don't get to pick what is included in it" is that if you change the rules, you get something else that is not $\mathbb R$. It does not help you to take the name $\mathbb R$ and use it for the new thing.

Comment: @Najib Idrissi $0 \cdot \infty$ is definitely $0$.

Comment: @Anixx What? No. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form This is basic calculus.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi what indetermonate form has to do with this? There is an indeterminant form "$0^0$", but $0^0=1$, there is indeterminate form "$1^\infty$", but $1^\infty=1$ on the extended real line. As we do not discull limits, indeterminate forms are irrelevant.

Comment: @Anixx You're verging into [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) territory. Feel free to ask a question on this site to get answers from people who are willing to bother with it. You're commenting on an eight-years-old post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A large reason why we don't include $\infty$ is because we can't really do arithmetic with it. $\mathbb{R}$ is a field, meaning that is satisfies a list of axioms that give it a certain structure. I suggest you look up these axioms if you're not familiar with them and see just how many of them start to fail if you try to include an $\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Yes, including $\infty$ may give you a few extra solutions to some problems, but it won't solve every problem ($x^2=-2$ for example) and in some cases, it will introduce answers you probably don't want (would $x=x+2$ now have the solution $x=\infty$?). All of this isn't really worth all of the issues you get for including $\infty$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 14):

By defining, for example, $+ \infty + n:= + \infty\ \forall n \in\mathbb{R}$ , we'd lose the group structure and this is no good for lots of purposes.

Answer (score 7):

There is no reason we can't add $\pm\infty$ to our set. Sometimes it is actually convenient to do so: in measure theory, it's common to work with "the extended non-negative reals" $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}\cup\{+\infty\}$ because it simplifies some common statements.

For doing arithmetic, it is very inconvenient however. In our standard $\mathbb R$, whenever we divide by something, we always have to make sure the denominator is not $0$, since dividing by $0$ is not allowed. This is an annoying artifact we have to live with as long as we want to divide things. Likewise, if we added $\pm\infty$ to our set, there is no good definition for what $\infty-\infty$ is, so whenever we subtract two variables, we have to make sure our numbers are not $\infty$. If we add two numbers $x+y$, and we happen to have $x=\infty$ and $y=-\infty$, we run into the same problem, so we can't even add two numbers without first checking they're not infinite! This is tedious, so we just decide not to include $\pm\infty$ in our set.

Answer (score 4):

While it is true that we could have "real" solutions to equations such as $2^x = 0$ in $\Bbb R \cup \{\infty\}$, we can get a similar amount of intuition just by saying that

$$ 2^x \rightarrow 0 \;\operatorname{as}\; x \rightarrow \infty $$

while not loosing a fair few important tools in analysis (well, maybe not in non-standard analysis, but I have little working knowledge about it) - how can you use the so-called "Axiom of Archimedes", which states that $\Bbb N$ is not bounded above in $\Bbb R$? While you could adapt this so it only holds for the non-infinite parts of our new number system, then what is the point of it? However, without such a tool, I don't see how it is possible to prove much in the system; I'm fairly sure something like the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem will not hold in $\Bbb R \cup \{\infty\}$.

Also, the comments of nik are also worth thinking about - is it possible to define $\infty$ in a way which doesn't lose the associative property of the ordinary reals?

Answer (score 2):

We do have several extensions to the "regular" real numbers including some sort of infinity.

I think of real numbers as just another step in a iterative construction, and thus there is no need to stop there.

We may start with the ***natural*** numbers: $1,2,3,...$ so we can do addition ,e.g. $1+2=3$, and multiplication, e.g. $2\times3=6$, but, say, we can not do every subtraction we may wish: $3-2=1$ is fine, but $2-3=??$ is not.

We extend it to **integer** numbers: $...,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...$ and now subtraction is OK for every element: $2-3=-1$

And extend to **rational** numbers to allow for division of integers (with the exception of dividing by 0). Somewhat surprisingly this is not the whole of *real* the numbers, so we drop in the *oddballs* ($\sqrt{2}$, $\pi$, etc.) and we get *all* the **real** numbers.

There is no reason to stop there, and we don't. There are quite a few [generalizations and extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_number#Generalizations_and_extensions). The [**extended real number line**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinely_extended_real_number_system) may be similar to what you seem to be looking for. The [surreal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surreal_number) are also quite interesting, I think - and I hope I can get to read more about them someday as they somehow fit the way I replied myself, years ago, the same question you're asking now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a lovely extension to $\mathbb{R}$ sometimes called max-plus (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-plus_algebra) in which one adds in $-\infty$ and redefines the key operations to get a very nice semi-ring. The great thing is that this system is very useful in solving a variety of problems in scheduling theory, and discrete dynamical systems. It allows one to solve problems such as deciding the maximum time of completion of a manufacturing process. (The sums are fun and make one think about the algebra used in solving equations in ordinary maths as well.)

If you prefer to add in $\infty$ you can consider (min-plus) and sometimes yoou need to complete in both directions! (see the  links at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-plus_algebra for lots more.)